# How to hide INFO and WARN?

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I'm using Docker Toolbox to use Spark on Windows 10.

The docker image is `sequenceiq/spark`. https://hub.docker.com/r/sequenceiq/spark/

However, a lot of "logs" are displayed.

```
scala> dataRDD.collect()
18/12/07 03:59:48 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
18/12/07 03:59:49 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: collect at <console>:32
18/12/07 03:59:49 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collect at <console>:32) with 1 output partitions
18/12/07 03:59:49 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (collect at <console>:32)
18/12/07 03:59:49 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
18/12/07 03:59:49 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
18/12/07 03:59:49 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at <console>:29), which has no missing parents
18/12/07 03:59:49 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.2 KB, free 357.5 KB)
18/12/07 03:59:49 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1870.0 B, free 359.3 KB)
18/12/07 03:59:49 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on localhost:39093 (size: 1870.0 B, free: 517.4 MB)
18/12/07 03:59:49 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 2 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
18/12/07 03:59:49 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at <console>:29)
...
```

Can I hide them thanks to an option during starting maybe?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simply

```
docker logs | grep -V INFO | grep -v WARN
```

?

Comment: I will try, thanks. And if I want to displayed them later? It exists a command? Thanks.

Comment: to hide INFO: grep -V INFO

to show only INFO: grep INFO

to show everything: remove grep